# SQL query to have certain rows on top based on a value in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following table

```
    CREATE TABLE #temp 
  ( 
     color1 VARCHAR(10),color2 VARCHAR(10),color3 VARCHAR(10) 
  ) 

INSERT INTO #temp 
VALUES      ('R','R','R'), 
            ('R','R','B'), 
            ('R','B','B'), 
            ('R','R','G'), 
            ('R','G','G'), 
            ('B','B','B'), 
            ('B','B','G'), 
            ('B','G','G'), 
            ('B','B','R'), 
            ('B','G','R'), 
            ('G','G','G'), 
            ('G','G','B'), 
            ('G','B','B'), 
            ('G','G','R'), 
            ('G','R','R')
```

I need the order the output such that the rows that contain values 'R' (in any of the three columns) should be the top of the result. Any suggestions ?

Note : The following query dosn't help.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   #temp 
ORDER  BY color1 DESC,color2 DESC,color3 DESC
```

The expected output is

```
color1  color2  color3
R   R   R
R   R   B
R   B   B
R   R   G
R   G   G
B   B   R
B   G   R
G   G   R
G   R   R
G   G   G
G   G   B
G   B   B
B   B   B
B   B   G
B   G   G
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ORDER BY CASE color1 WHEN 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END

Comment: Aaron, that is a good answer, why do you put it in the comments instead of an answer post?

Comment: @AaronBertrand The value of 'R' in all three columns should be considered.

Comment: Then just add two more similar case statements to your order by clause.

Comment: @Muthukumar Ok, SHOW us what you mean. This does not mean editing the question to say "any of the 3 columns." You need to be *specific* about *exactly* how the sample data shown should be ordered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TEMP
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Color1='R' OR Color2='R' OR Color3='R' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: @Muthukumar I don't see any down-votes, and I certainly didn't, but this query can't possibly produce the result you illustrated in the question. Oh, which you have now changed. Brilliant.

Comment: Haha... yes, the expected output kept changing, but the description did not. The task was to put any row containing an 'R' in one of the three columns at the top. This does that. There were no further specifications.

Comment: "Expected output" is a very important part of specifications (and [these were just wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24042778/2)) - much more so than word problems. I'm not complaining about the answer, just demonstrating to the OP that they need to be clear about both.

Comment: Fair enough. That's one of the never ending problems of stack exchange.